# return a variable or constant in a function in an ES6 react class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have a function which I am returning a variable to create a list item. The function happily returns the unordered list but not the item for which I want to populate it with. I would appreciate some direction to why i have gone wrong.

**Header.js**

```
export class Header extends Component  {

    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    NavMenu () {

       let links = () => (

           <li>hey</li>
    );

     return (
         <ul className="nav navbar-navs">
             {links}
         </ul>
       );
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="container-fluid">
                            {this.NavMenu()}
                </div>
        )
     }

   }

   export default Header;
```

**Thank you :)**

Comment: Should be `{links()}` - you've got to execute the arrow function to return the list item.

Comment: Or simply keeping `let links  = (<li>Hey</li>);`  should do in this case.

Comment: @AndrewLi  tnxs  The answer was in reach, but too much time in front of a PC can cause you to overlook basic things.

Comment: @SachinGadagi yes thats another useful option that I could implement maybe applied depending on the user case. Tnxs again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`links` is a function that returns a Element. You should call it like `links()`

```js
class Header extends React.Component  {

    constructor () {
        super();
    }

     NavMenu () {

       let links = () => (

           <li>hey</li>
    );

     return (
         <ul className="nav navbar-navs">
             {links()}
         </ul>
       );
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="container-fluid">
                            {this.NavMenu()}
                </div>
        )
     }
     
 }
 ReactDOM.render(<Header/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example was very helpful to me and others who do the same.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are using {links} variable which is pointing to a function.

Now, either you call the respective function using **links()** to return a value 
OR 
Just assign a direct value to links variable.

```
NavMenu () {

 let links = (<li>hey</li>);

 return (
     <ul className="nav navbar-navs">
         {links}
     </ul>
   );
}
```